# Error in insert syntax

Tags: php, mysql

I have been working on a simple php code which links a html form to a mySQL database. I have installed xampp and am running Apache and mySQL but I cannot seem to solve the problem. [Error Alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHQCp.png)

So I've tried several different things in order to fix this syntax error: [Syntax Error Location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzhBA.png)

This has been a very big annoyance so if anyone could help me out it would be greatly appreciated. I also attacted my entire php code but it cut off the php ending. [Entire Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPAZV.png)

Thanks and hope to hear from you soon!

Comment: You have the column names list and the VALUES list the wrong way round

Comment: And in future questions please post the code as text and not as pictures of text

Comment: Tell me; would *you* be able to run what you posted as an image or would retype that? I thought not. You need to post actual code here.

Comment: You also have single quotes `'` around the table name and field names. This is not valid for MySQL, you should use no quotes at all, or, if you need to escape reserved words, use backticks `\``

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Answer (score 1):

Replace your insert with following insert

```
$insert = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `general` (email, psw, firstname, lastname) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
$insert->bind_param("ssss", $email, $psw, $firstname, $lastname);
```

and then instead of

```
$conn->query($sql);
```

use

```
$insert->execute();
```

This way you will protect your database from SQL injection attack. Well at least in this case. This is called prepared statement and you should use them everywhere, where user created data may enter your Database query.

Comment: Do you know how [`bind_param()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) works? It isn't shown in your answer.